# What is the relation Between Stand Alone Complex and Individual Eleven ideology?

Tags: cyborg, ghost-in-the-shell, ghost-in-the-shell-sac

Is it possible that Individual Eleven ideology is based on Stand Alone Complex?

By the way to be everything clear could you describe me what Stand Alone Complex is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stand Alone Complex is a philosophical construct; A copy of something that does not exist, or to make it clear, a copy that *does* exist but the thing it *copies* ( The Original ) does *not* exist. I prefer to imagine it like Calculus, which was invented by Newton and Liebnitz at the same time  without either man knowing of the others work - as if they both copied it from an original work that was viewed by both of them , but in reality didn't really exist.

The Individual Eleven on the other hand, is a movement of political revolution based on a non-existent essay by a political writer; He had notes for it, but eventually decided not to write the essay. Although a fake document exists that purports to be that essay, it only exists in a digital format that hides it's purpose - to carry a virus that manipulates the reader into becoming part of an anarchist plot to cause violence at protests, which later is further utilized by a small government cadre to foment trouble among refugees to create the justification for martial law and military action.

So, summing up ( Why do I sound like Batou here? ), it's fair to say that like the Stand Alone Complex, the Individual Eleven "Manifesto" is a copy of a nonexistent item, but it is in itself quite different as it's not what it purports to be, where the Complex is straightforward in intent.

Comment: Coming from outside the franchise I still have no idea what these terms are in relation to the franchise.  Ate they generic terms or do they relate to something from the show?

Comment: I suppose the concepts do exist in the real world, but the show uses them specifically. So you can say they are "in-universe".
 Well, you *could* say that anyone talking about "The Report From Iron Mountain" in real life is similar to the Individual Eleven for exactly the same reason though :)

Answer (score 2):

The Stand Alone Complex:

> An accidental collectivism made up of detached individuals, resembling a highly organized conspiracy and lacking a deliberate origin.” From: Urban Dictionary

Comment: I guess that's a little clearer on that one.

Comment: Oh, found a real life one. "The Butler Did It" is described in a 1928 essay on detective fiction writing as being an overused cliche . . . However, no one can find ANY story in which the Butler actually did it before this time. Agatha Christie had the murderer *pretend* to be a butler to gain access to the victim in one novel, however that's it. So, copycats afterwards of which there are many are copying an original that does not exist much as Aramaki described the Stand Alone Complex.